# Android using PlaceAutoCompleteActivity (Google Places API)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have made a very simple example of the issue I am having with the `PlaceAutoCompelteActivity`. My map will show on the screen, along with 2 text search bars on top. The issue is that once I click in the textview, a keyboard will come up and a cursor will blink in the textview (as expected), however after I type the first letter (if i type quickly I can get 2 letters in), the keyboard will go away and the search box will blank out and the cursor will go away (return to the preclicked on state.) Here is a link to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=en

The code for the simple activity and the xml file are below:

java activity:

```
package com.blah.android.backseatbuddy;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class RouteActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    //    private EditText beginningDestination;
//    private EditText endingDestination;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment beginningDestination;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment endingDestination;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route);

        beginningDestination = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.beginning_destination);
        beginningDestination.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("beginningDestination ", "Place: " + place.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("beginningDestination ", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

        endingDestination = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ending_destination);
        endingDestination.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("endingDestination ", "Place: " + place.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("endingDestination ", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
//        beginningDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.beginning_destination);
//        endingDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ending_destination);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

and xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFragment"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/beginning_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ending_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.greg.android.backseatbuddy.RouteActivity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just ran your code, and could not reproduce the issue.  Running on a Nexus 6 with Android 6.0.1

Comment: @Daniel Nugent hm so the autocomplete worked fine or the code didn't run?

Comment: I am using a Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0

Comment: The code ran just fine for me with no problems.  I was able to type locations in both PlaceAutocompleteFragment fields.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the attention to my issue however your comment along with felix's attempted answer led me to the solution. See below felix's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to insert your own API key (if you haven't done so already) that can be acquired through the Google developers console.
Details here:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup?hl=en
Also, in the Google developers console, add Google Places API to the list of enabled API's in your project.

Comment: My api key is already obtained and configured properly or else the map and the search bars wouldn't be showing up at all

Comment: i apologize, your answer was in fact pretty close to what needed to be done. I had already retrieved and inserted my api key for the project into the appropriate (google_maps_api.xml) file but I had not gone and added the google places android api to my "enabled APIs" section in the google developers console (the maps android api was already there so thats why the map worked). If you want to update your answer I will happily accept.

Comment: I edited my answer. :-)  If it is still incomplete please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: after enabling also , the problem persists ! help me