# Android Google places PlaceAutocomplete views close automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I am using Google Maps V2 API Key, but when I use PlaceAutocompleteFragment or PlaceAutocomplete as activity it takes first character and close the view. There is no error message or warning.

Comment: See here also, same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582898/android-using-placeautocompleteactivity-google-places-api

Answer (score 4):

I found that to use Google Places Maps key will work. But you need to go to Google Developer Console and enable Places API.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue for myself. Turns out i was registering the key against google maps api instead of the geocoding. Make sure u use the following in your manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```